# How to handle double quotes and back slash while parsing the json in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a program which returns json data which I will store in a string and creating an object out of it.

The JSON is like this

try.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

echo '{"Directory": "{hell\o}"}'
```

Python program:

```
import subprocess,json
returned_value =subprocess.check_output("try.sh")
obj = json.loads(returned_value)
pprint.pprint(obj)
```

I am getting the error as

> ValueError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 21 (char 20)

If \ or " is present in the output how can I handle it considering I have no control over try.sh ?

Comment: If the program inserts backslashes where they don't belong, it's basically unreliable. How do you know if `"\uaaaa\a\b"` means what it really means, or if some of the backslashes should be removed?

Comment: You can always preprocess it before passing to json parser. With replace or something.

Comment: For your immediate problem, `returned_value.replace(r'\o','o')` would seem to return valid JSON.

Comment: @tripleee if it's like "dir": "{"/var/tmp/"}" how to handle this?

Comment: This seems entirely different from the question you posted. It is hard to generalize any advice based on a single sample. `returned_value.replace('"{"','{"').replace('"}"','"}')` might both work and generalize nicely, but all of this is sounding more and more like an [XY Problem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 1):

You could use str.translate on your returned_value :

```
escaped_returned_value = returned_value.translate(str.maketrans({"\\":  r"\\"}))
```

Output :

```
 '{"Directory": "{hell\\o}"}'
```

Comment: This will obviously wreck a lot of valid JSON which contains backslashes which actually belong there.

Answer (score -1):

In [59]: data = "{hell\o}"

In [60]: data

Out[60]: '{hell\o}'

In [61]: json.dumps(data)

Out[61]: '"{hell\\o}"'

See this list of special character used in JSON :

```
\b  Backspace (ascii code 08)
\f  Form feed (ascii code 0C)
\n  New line
\r  Carriage return
\t  Tab
\"  Double quote
\\  Backslash character
```